# Where did the Buddha say: "What a person considers and reflects upon for a long time, to that his mind will bend and incline."?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon

> As the Buddha says, "What a person considers and reflects upon for a
> long time, to that his mind will bend and incline."

The above quote is from Nyanaponika Thera, found [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel006.html#:%7E:text=Meditative%20development%20of%20the%20sublime%20states%20will%20be%20aided%20by,mind%20will%20bend%20and%20incline.%22) at Access to Insight.

Does anyone know where the Buddha says that, in the Pali Canon?

A [google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22What%20a%20person%20considers%20and%20reflects%20upon%20for%20a%20long%20time%2C%20to%20that%20his%20mind%20will%20bend%20and%20incline.%22&lr=&safe=images&as_qdr=all&sxsrf=AJOqlzWaPNrHSlYXrghlXktMhmk5FzV3WQ%3A1673269610221&ei=ahG8Y_yZDeebptQPl5G3wAk&ved=0ahUKEwj89uuFx7r8AhXnjYkEHZfIDZgQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22What%20a%20person%20considers%20and%20reflects%20upon%20for%20a%20long%20time%2C%20to%20that%20his%20mind%20will%20bend%20and%20incline.%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWABgvQVoAHAAeACAAVCIAVCSAQExmAEAoAECoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) search of the quote was not helpful.

Comment: " stress results either in bewilderment or in search."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from here:

> "Whatever a monk keeps pursuing with his thinking & pondering, that
> becomes the inclination of his awareness.
> [MN 19](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.019.than.html) (translated by Ven. Thanissaro)

> “Bhikkhus, whatever a bhikkhu frequently thinks and ponders upon, that
> will become the inclination of his mind.
> [MN 19](https://suttacentral.net/mn19/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false) (translated by Ven. Bodhi)

> Whatever a mendicant frequently thinks about and considers becomes
> their heart’s inclination.
> [MN 19](https://suttacentral.net/mn19/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) (translated by Ven. Sujato)